# How to see $log calls in Terminal when running angularjs unit tests with karma?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angular-seed

In a project based on angular-seed project, I am running unit tests with `./scripts/test.sh --log-level debug` but none of the log messages that I see are coming from my app. How do I get to see them? In my app, I am logging with `$log`.

Comment: in the terminal you can only see console.log() calls defined in your spec file, not in your app

Comment: See my answer below. I got to see my app logs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Got it working! Had I used `console.log` directly it would have worked but now that I am using `$log` I had to patch it in a `beforeEach` (looks like by default it wasn't wired by angularjs):

```
$provide.value('$log', console);
```

Answer (score 15):

Thanks.  As mentioned, tests can inject `console` for `$log` using `$provide`.  For posterity, `$provide` is not available via `inject(function(...) { ... })` but instead [must be injected into a function argument to `module`](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1517/supplying-mocks-for-services-via-provide):

```
beforeEach(module('myapp', function($provide) {
  // Output messages
  $provide.value('$log', console);
}));
```

Comment: Shouldn't @Carl get credit for this answer? I guess not, I didn't look at the time stamps. NM

Comment: Yes, I built on the earlier answer because it was not obvious to me how to properly override the `$log` service in a test.  As mentioned here, `$provide` must be injected using `module`.

Answer (score 4):

for clarity, you must structure it like this:

```
beforeEach(module('myapp'));

beforeEach(module('myapp', function($provide) {
  // Output messages
  $provide.value('$log', console);
}));
```